# Get element with internals like String with Android simplexml

Tags: android, simple-framework

I receive xml and want to get all content of element **Value** to the String.
Now by using `@Element(name = "Value") public String value` I can get only empty value. I want to get `<SomeElement>...</SomeElement><AnotherElement>...</AnotherElement>...` in String value. How I can do this by using simplexml without parsing each internal element?

```
<Product>   
    <Value>
        <SomeElement>...</SomeElement>
        <AnotherElement>...</AnotherElement>
        ...
    </Value>
    <Id>1</Id>
    ...
</Product>


@Root(name="Product")
public static class Product {
    @Element(name = "Value") 
    public String value;

    @Element(name = "Id") 
    public String id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would an array of Strings be acceptable? You can always connect them into a single String later on and it is the most stright-forward solution for a situation like yours, where you have different tags. If so, try the below code:

```
@Root(name="Product")
public static class Product {
    @ElementArray(name = "Value") 
    public String[] value;

    @Element(name = "Id") 
    public String id;
}
```